# sql table join product notation system

Tags: php, sql

[image]
Hello I have a rating system I want to check that the user who posts an opinion on a product on my site buys it well and I want to ensure that he can give an opinion on each item he has purchased only

here are the sql tables in image it is composed:[ users ][ details] [ sales] [product] [products]

the [details] table is the products that the user has ordered with the id of the order as well as all the ids of the products that order it the sales table is the user's orders in my case the only user who ordered is id number 9 and he performed 2 commands the user id and stored in the session under the name of $user $user['id'] I think the problem comes from the product id because the product id and transform into product name so like this
$slug = slugify($name);
$name = $_POST['name'];
its fact that rather than having an id in the search bar there is the name of the product but always has the id of the product in the table of course well for the opinion system it's the same thing it"s $pid which retrieves the product id via the get and store in the $pid and pid returns the product name or computer for example instead of id=8
product=hp-pavilion-power-580-015na-gaming-pc

here I hope you understood me to help me thank you and the product table is id and users is id also there is nothing else to recup.[image]

Comment: `I think the problem comes`...and what exactly _is_ the problem? We have only a rather dense description (use some punctuation and formatting please!!!), isolated code snippets and some pictures of your database. I don't see an explanation of what the issue is, or any code which might help us to investigate it. Please see [ask] and how to create a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM sales  WHERE user_id=".$user['id']."");
    
     $stmt->execute(['user_id'=>$user['id']]);

Comment: what I want to do is allow the user who has ordered a product to be able to give an opinion on the product that only buys it, not the others, you have understood, for that I have to make a big join between the tables that I have on the images the session stock the user id and the product id and send in the contact form in POST